# import statement for node.js incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

We're trying to use the latest standards and are updated our javascript files `require` sections. We're trying to updated this:

```js
const {app: { port, test_var }} = require('../config/config')
const app = require('./app')
```

to this:

```js
import {app: { port, test_var }} from '../config/config'
import app from './app'
```

But the following error is thrown:

```
import {app: { port, test_var }} from '../config/config'
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

What would be the correct syntax? I can't find an example for this specific case in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers).

This is the content of `config.js`:

```js
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
console.log(`Environment '${env}'`)

const development = {
  app: {
    port: parseInt(process.env.DEV_APP_PORT) || 3000,
    test_var: parseInt(process.env.TEST_VAR),
    // Generate token:
    // require('crypto').randomBytes(128).toString('hex')
    accessTokenKey: process.env.accessTokenKey || '5ef37718e7c74b',
    refreshTokenKey: process.env.refreshTokenKey || 'j;9f0as8098fas'
  },
  db: {
    host: process.env.DEV_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: parseInt(process.env.DEV_DB_PORT) || 27017,
    name: process.env.DEV_DB_NAME || 'db'
  }
}

const production = {
  app: {
    port: parseInt(process.env.PROD_APP_PORT) || 8080,
    accessTokenKey: process.env.accessTokenKey,
    refreshTokenKey: process.env.refreshTokenKey
  },
  db: {
    host: process.env.PROD_DB_HOST || 'ServerProd',
    port: parseInt(process.env.PROD_DB_PORT) || 27017,
    name: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME || 'NodeDB'
  }
}

const config = {
  development,
  production
}

module.exports = config[env]
```

Comment: There might not be a direct equivalent. `import { app as appConfig } from '../config/config'` then `const port = appConfig.port` will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use module.exports then, because that's old way that works with require.
Please look at

[Export ECMA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

===========================================

Edit my answer because first is not clear.

Import clause in import ES6 isn't the same as destructuring. There is a syntactic similarity if you read doc. about import, but there are no constructors for that.
Use another statement for destructuring after the import

Comment: I've added `"type": "module"` to `package.json` so it should be supported according to the docs.

Comment: In ECMA named imports do not destructure.. Use another statement for destructuring after the import.